# Issue with power shell command get-content and add-content

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to create a service report using power shell(using existing code) and I am very new to power shell but I keep getting the error ( see below  .

```
Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Add-Content'.
At 
 C:\HYPERION_DOCS\Projects\SERVICESMonitoring\CheckServiceStatus.ps1:19 char:1
+ Add-Content $report "<html>" Add-Content $report "<head>" Add-Content ...

##############################################################################
$checkrep = Test-Path “.\report.htm”
If ($checkrep -like “True”)
{
Remove-Item “.\report.htm”

}
New-Item “.\report.htm” -type file
################################ADD HTML 
Content#############################

Add-Content $report “<html>” Add-Content $report “<head>” Add-Content 
$report “<meta http-equiv=’Content-Type’ content=’text/html; charset=iso- 
8859-1'>” Add-Content $report ‘<title>Hyperion Services Report</title>’ 
Add-Content $report ‘<img src=”Toplogo.png” alt=”Infosys” style=”width:100%;height:25%;” align=”Center”>’ add-content $report ‘<STYLE TYPE=”text/css”>’ add-content $report  “<!–” add-content $report  “td {” add-content $report  “font-family: Tahoma;” add-content $report  “font-size: 11px;” add-content $report  “border-top: 1px solid #999999;” add-content $report  “border-right: 1px solid #999999;” add-content $report  “border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;” add-content $report  “border-left: 1px solid #999999;” add-content $report  “padding-top: 0px;” add-content $report  “padding-right: 0px;” add-content $report  “padding-bottom: 0px;” add-content $report  “padding-left: 0px;” add-content $report  “}” add-content $report  “body {” add-content $report  “margin-left: 5px;” add-content $report  “margin-top: 5px;” add-content $report  “margin-right: 0px;” add-content $report  “margin-bottom: 10px;” add-content $report  “” add-content $report  “table {” add-content $report  “border: thin solid #000000;” add-content $report  “}” add-content $report  “–>” add-content $report  “</style>” Add-Content $report “</head>” Add-Content $report “<body>” add-content $report  “<table width=’100%’>” add-content $report  “<tr bgcolor=’Lavender’>” add-content $report  “<td colspan=’7' height=’25’ align=’center’>” add-content $report  “<font face=’tahoma’ color=’#003399' size=’4'><strong>Hyperion Services Report</strong></font>” add-content $report  “</td>” add-content 
$report  “</tr>” add-content $report  “</table>”  add-content $report  “<table width=’100%’>” Add-Content $report “<tr bgcolor=’IndianRed’>” Add-Content
```

$report  “**Server Name**” Add-Content 
   $report “**Service Name**” Add-Content 
    $report  “**Status**” Add-Content 
    $report “”

......

Answer (score 0):

you don't have $report set as "report.htm"

You could also simply just use `out-file report.htm -append`

Also `convertto-html` is an option to save you a load of typing. as it auto builds your page for you... and then you just out-file the result... (a very short sample below)

```
$body = ‘<img src=”Toplogo.png” alt=”Infosys” style=”width:100%;height:25%;” align=”Center”>’'###... etc... 
ConvertTo-HTML -Body "$body" -Title "Hyperion Services Report" -CssUri c:\style.css | Out-File c:\report.htm
```

adapted from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/hh127059(v=msdn.10))

Comment: HI ,in the code I have provided I had already create a variable for $report $report = ".\report.htm"

##############################################################################
$checkrep = Test-Path ".\report.htm"
If ($checkrep -like "True")
{
Remove-Item ".\report.htm"

}
New-Item ".\report.htm" -type file

Comment: I suggested an edit. I still missed some code. Please correct the option to reflect what is code. Also I still don't see what you're saying. But I do believe you put that. I hope you figure it out either way.

Answer (score 0):

i see two problems with your posted code.

[1] lack of line breaks OR `;` to indicate end-of-command
the error you list mentions trying to use `Get-Content` as an *argument* for a positional parameter.

that means just exactly what it says. [*grin*] you need to put EACH cmdlet & its parameters on its own line, OR delimit the commands with semicolons.

[2] apparent MSWord "smart quotes"
your code shows curved/curled double and single quotes. those a NOT the same as standard straight quotes. PoSh will often get very confused about where a string begins/ends when those peculiar [but very pretty] quotes are used.

i *strongly* suggest you replace those with straight quotes.

take care,
lee

Comment: I removed  all the  curved double quotes with straight double quotes I still get the same error .Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Add-Content'.
At C:\HYPERION_DOCS\Projects\SERVICESMonitoring\CheckServiceStatus.ps1:19 char:1
+ Add-Content $report "<html>" Add-Content $report "<head>" Add-Content CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand

Comment: @Ashish - you seem to have ignored the 1st item. do you STILL have the following ... `Add-Content $report “<html>” Add-Content $report “<head>”` code? please note that i mentioned you MUST provide some sort of command delimiter. either put a `;` between those `Add-Content` cmdlet sections OR use newlines. [*grin*]

Comment: thanks I was able to fix the issue for get-content and add content .How ever now I am stuck with the below code

Comment: thanks I was able to fix the issue for get-content and add content .How ever now I am stuck with the below code Function servicestatus ($serverlist, $serviceslist){foreach ($machineName in $serverlist){foreach($service in $serviceslist){$serviceStatus = get-service -ComputerName $machineName -Name $service if($serviceStatus.status -eq "Running"){Write-Host $machineName `t $serviceStatus.name `t $serviceStatus.status -ForegroundColor Green $svcName = $serviceStatus.name $svcState = $serviceStatus.status;Add-Content $report "<tr>"

Comment: I was Finally able to fix the issue thanks for all your help